# In the House Robber problem, why does the even case look at the odd case?

Tags: algorithm

The whole idea of [the problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/) is you can't rob consecutive houses.

So this solution works and is based on the idea of considering even houses or odd houses (which skips a house in each case):

```
public int rob(int[] nums) {
    int robEven = 0, robOdd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if ( i % 2 == 0) { // even
            robEven = Math.max(robEven + nums[i], robOdd);
        } else {
            robOdd = Math.max(robOdd + nums[i], robEven);
        }
    }
    return Math.max(robEven, robOdd);
}
```

But, my question is about the `Math.max` calculation:

```
robEven = Math.max(robEven + nums[i], robOdd);
```

In the even case, why are you allowed to consider the odd case since you can't go from an odd house to an even house because they would be next door?

I thought the solution would be like this:

```
public int rob(int[] nums) {
    int robEven = 0, robOdd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if ( i % 2 == 0) { // even
            robEven = Math.max(robEven + nums[i], robEven);
        } else {
            robOdd = Math.max(robOdd + nums[i], robOdd);
        }
    }
    return Math.max(robEven, robOdd);
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: You're going from an even house *that you're not robbing* to an odd house which is next door to that.

Comment: It's comparing the current max of what you're robbing to the one you're not robbing. Is robbing this even house a greater amount than what's the total for the odd houses?  [I think in the if, it should be robEven+=nums[i], (of for odds), then the Math.max return would work...but that's me contemplating without testing it. Guess I should go try it.]